# Как ограничить количество попыток угадать число

Tags: java

В общем получается какой-то бред, выводит бесконечно имена игроков со значением попыток от 10 до 0 зацикленно. А нужно просто ограничить количество попыток для каждого игрока.

Спасибо.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessNumber {

    private int computerNumber;
    private Player playerOne;
    private Player playerTwo;
    private boolean isWin;
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public GuessNumber(Player playerOne, Player playerTwo) {
        this.playerOne = playerOne;
        this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    }

    public void startGame() {
        isWin = false;
        computerNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
            System.out.println("Guess the number of the computer from 1 to 100");
        do {
            inputUserNumber(playerOne);
            guessNumber(playerOne);
            inputUserNumber(playerTwo);
            guessNumber(playerTwo);
        } while (!isWin);
    }

    private void inputUserNumber(Player player) {
        System.out.println(player.getName() + ", enter number: ");
    }

    private void guessNumber(Player player) {
        do {
            for (int attemptsNum = 10; attemptsNum > 0; --attemptsNum) {
                if(player.getNumber() == computerNumber) {
                    System.out.println(player.getName() + ", you won!");
                    isWin = true;
                } else if (player.getNumber() < computerNumber) {
                    System.out.println(player.getName() + ", введенное вами число меньше того, что загадал компьютер" + "Попыток осталось: " + attemptsNum);
                } else if (player.getNumber() > computerNumber) {
                    System.out.println(player.getName() + ", введенное вами число больше того, что загадал компьютер" + "Попыток осталось: " + attemptsNum);
                }
            }
        } while (player.getNumber() != computerNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: `scan` вы по приколу создали или для дела? Достаточно одного цикла `for` без `do while`

Comment: @ArchDemon, а причем здесь scan?

Comment: покажите, где вы считываете число от игрока? В том коде, что вы показали, считывания не происходит нигде.

Comment: @tym32167, есть еще два класса, в этом классе вся логика игры

Comment: а в этом-то классе scan зачем?